# How can a button get the focus?

Tags: android, button

There are quite a few posts touching this topic.  I thought I should ask this simple question hoping to clarify this.

I am unable to achieve setting the focus on a button.  I know I probably miss something fundamental. Here is the simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:focusable="true" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

The following is the simple code in onCreate():

```
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setFocusable(true);
        button.requestFocus();
        button.setText("Debug");  //Just to show the code here has been executed
```

It simply does not work (i.e. the button does not get the focus).

Any correction of my error or misunderstanding will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

update your code:

```
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setFocusable(true);
        button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);///add this line
        button.requestFocus();
        button.setText("Debug");
```

Comment: The button will have Focus otherwise too but you don't see it. Visual focus is only in [TouchMode](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2008/12/touch-mode.html)

Comment: Thank you all for the prompt response and clarification.  Apparently I did not understand what "focus" means in the particular context.  Now I wonder what utility that a button gaining focus without showing it has.

Comment: Say you have a keyboard attached to your device (like emulator has) or you have a device with a d-pad and you hit enter / click dpad. Whatever has focus get's called now. If you just use you app with your fingers then you can usually just ignore focus.

Comment: Thanks, zapl, for the elucidation.  I have to admit that I am still having hard time understanding this behavior. If I use a keyboard, I personally would prefer seeing the visual feedback telling me which widget is focused.  When I tried this on another layout with buttons and edittexts on an emulator, I could get a button receiving the focus (orange background) by using the tab key, but not in code (before using setFocusableInTouchMode(true)).  However, I could get an edittext in focus visually in code using requestFocus() without setFocusableInTouchMode(true). A bit confusing to me.

Comment: @Hong any luck..i also facing same problem...in my case it show focus some times and some time not.

Comment: @Hong no probs let me check once...problem is it give me some right result and some time wrong..might be some problem in my view-code. thanks :)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K  thanks for the great answer, but I need to understand what is the meaning of `setFocusableInTouchMode` if you please :) as I read the documentation but didn't get it

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes it so that you have to touch the button twice to trigger a "click" event.